# Atomic widget to represent financial amount in guidewire pcf?

Tags: guidewire, gosu

Which atomic widget we need to use to represent the Financial Amount like Monetary Amount, etc in the PCF?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "MonetaryAmount Cell" in case the widget should be with List View PCF file or if you wanted to show in Detail View then go for "MonetaryAmount Input". Both should be available in Studio Tool Box.